# Why the Directory structure of maven project is wrong and how to fix it?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I used the idea to establish a maven project，The directory structure should be look like this

[image]

Than I use the same steps to create another project，but it look like this now：

[image]

How to restore it to normal？

Comment: You should close the project and reimport it from the maven POM file (pom.xml), and that should fix it.

Comment: @ Engineer Dollery thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It is normal, you just have package structure set to hierarchical and not flat. Or your project is not recognized as java/maven project.